# Unable to initialise a git repo because .git: No such file or directory

Tags: git-for-windows

I am recapping on git in preparation for a project at work and I am falling at the first hurdle when trying to initialise a repo.

I ran the following in GIT BASH (opened as administrator):

```
cd Users
cd <myuser>
cd Documents
cd git_recap
cd test_project
git init
```

The last command returns the following error:

```
C:Users/<myuser>/Documents/git_recap/test_project/.git: No such file or directory
```

My research tells me that this is a permissions error. I can repeat the exact same steps on my personal computer (not my work one) and it works fine. The problem is that I have no idea which permissions are causing the problem.

I checked the folder permissions for test_project as follows:

```
cd ..
ls -la
```

which returns (surmised):

```
drwxr-xr-x ./
drwxr-xr-x ../
drwxr-xr-x test_project/
```

I thought: maybe I need to open this folder up for everyone to write to it - fool proof method. I ran:

```
chmod 777 test_project/
```

Which returned:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'test_project/': Permission denied
```

I then repeated this process up the folder hierarchy and received the same error message all the way up to the root folder of . I now wanted to see the permissions of all users:

```
cd ..
ls -la
```

Which returned:

```
drwxr-xr-x <myuser>/
```

To confirm that the issue is with the   directory and my permissions within it, I decided to try initialise the repo in the root:

```
cd <my_user>/
git init
```

To my surprise, this worked and the repo was succesfully initialised.

Obviously I do not want to initialise my repo here. I want to initialise it in the appropriate test folder.

Any clues what might be wrong and what I might try to correct this?

EDIT

I get identical results when doing the same set of steps from command line (also ran as administrator)

Comment: Can you show the Windows permissions and the owner of `test_project` (and the `.git` directory if it exists)?

Comment: How do I show the owner? Is this just a screengrab of the Security tab on folder properties that you want to see? .git does not exist and the test_project folder is empty

Comment: I believe I have worked it out and will post an edit on my post for those interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stumbled across what I believe is the solution: Windows Security Controlled Folder Access.

This feature is enabled by default on my work laptop and prevents tampering with certain User folders to provide better security in the event of a breach - in particular ransomware.

Unfortunately for me, IT have the power to turn it off - not me.